# If God did not exist, He would have to be invented

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does this quote by Voltaire:

"If God did not exist, He would have to be invented"

mean:

Even if God did not exist, it would be necessary to invent one, because we always want to have a god, real or imaginary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about an author's intent - which is unanswerable unless the author tells us.

Comment: Especially since Voltaire did not say *"Si Dieu n'existait pas, il faudrait l'inventer"*  in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement by Voltaire was written in 1768, in response to a controversial work, The Three Impostors.

This essentially reiterates the importance of the concept of God for the society's well being. He considered that a belief in God entails a belief in afterlife, that can be considered to be a deterrent for anti-social forces that elude capture and punishment in the mortal life.

Voltaire develops the idea that the existence of God (or the belief therein) helps establish social order.

So, yes. The statement by Voltaire does mean what you think it does.